# Can't add compiler options for nvcc in nsight eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda

How do I add options to my nvcc using nsight eclipse. I tried to modify the command option Under Project->Properties->Build->Settings->Tool Settings-> NVCC Compiler. I changed it from "nvcc" to "nvcc --someoption". However when it compiles I see this output "/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -O3 -ccbin gcc-4.9 -std=c++11 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -odir "." -M -o "binomial.d" "../binomial.cu"

Notice that --someoption in not in it. How can I add an option in eclipse?  I also noticed that I can change the command from nvcc to some gibberish and it still compiles so I think that option does not affect anything.  If so how can I add compiler options which eclipse does not include in its gui.

Comment: Note that the only options you should be specifying are ones that are recognized by `nvcc`.  Which options did you want to specify?  The nsight EE GUI has options to specify most of the compiler options that you are likely to use.  Note there is an `-optf` switch that is selectable under Project Settings... Build ... Settings...Tool Settings...Miscellaneous which will allow you to specify a file containing additional command line switches

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `-optf` switch that is selectable under Project Settings... Build ... Settings...Tool Settings...Miscellaneous and add your own file to the project that contains whatever compiler switches you want to add.

I think most compiler switches are already covered in the GUI, however.

Comment: -dc (--device-c) is not present as an option as far as I can see

Comment: That will be used automatically  if you select an appropriate project type that calls for separate compilation.